# How to import all fields from xls as strings into a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import a file from xlsx into a Python Pandas dataframe. I would like to prevent fields/columns being interpreted as integers and thus losing leading zeros or other desired heterogenous formatting.

So for an Excel sheet with 100 columns, I would do the following using a dict comprehension with range(99).

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'C:\DemoFile.xlsx'

fields = {col: str for col in range(99)}

df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname=0, converters=fields)
```

These import files do have a varying number of columns all the time, and I am looking to handle this differently than changing the range manually all the time.

Does somebody have any further suggestions or alternatives for reading Excel files into a dataframe and treating all fields as strings by default?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(r'C:\DemoFile.xlsx')
ncols = xl.book.sheet_by_index(0).ncols
df = xl.parse(0, converters={i : str for i in range(ncols)})
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [261]: type(xl)
Out[261]: pandas.io.excel.ExcelFile

In [262]: type(xl.book)
Out[262]: xlrd.book.Book
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I did not find `.book.sheet_by_index(0).ncols` in the Pandas package at all, is it part of `xlrd`? I would like to read further about it.

Comment: @DanielaK, yes, it's a `xlrd.book.Book` object - please see UPDATE section in the answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `dtype=str` when calling `.read_excel()`

```
import pandas as pd
filename = 'C:\DemoFile.xlsx'

df = pd.read_excel(filename, dtype=str)
```

Answer (score 0):

the usual solution is:

1. read in one row of data just to get the column names and number of columns
2. create the dictionary automatically where each columns has a string type
3. re-read the full data using the dictionary created at step 2.